Quarkus/Vertx: propagate MDC in WorkerExecutor
I'd like to use MDC or something similar to put some additional context informations in my logs, using Quarkus and Vertx.
The application is just a command line, not a REST server or any conventional server.
Here an example of code:
@QuarkusMain
public class Test implements QuarkusApplication {

    @Inject
    Vertx vertx;

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) throws Exception {

        MDC.put("mytest1", "hallo1");

        Log.info("initial message");

        WorkerExecutor executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("worker", 20);
        executor.executeBlocking(() -> {
            MDC.put("mytest2", "hallo2");
            ContextualData.put("mytest3", "hallo3");
            Log.info("message in worker");
            return null;
        });

        Log.info("final message");
        Quarkus.waitForExit();
        return 0;
    
    }
}

here the dependencies part of the pom:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-vertx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactiverse</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactiverse-contextual-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

and here the application.properties:
%dev.quarkus.log.console.enable=true
%dev.quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%-27C{1}:%-3L] (%-20t) -%X{mytest1}- -%X{mytest2}- [%X{mytest3}] %s%e%n
%dev.quarkus.log.min-level=TRACE

That's is what I get if I start the application with DEV profile :
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :29 ] (Quarkus Main Thread ) -hallo1- -- [] initial message
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :39 ] (Quarkus Main Thread ) -hallo1- -- [] final message
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :35 ] (worker-1            ) -- -- [] message in worker

That's what I would like to have:
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :29 ] (Quarkus Main Thread ) -hallo1- -- [] initial message
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :39 ] (Quarkus Main Thread ) -hallo1- -- [] final message
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :35 ] (worker-1            ) -- -hallo2- [] message in worker

or
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :29 ] (Quarkus Main Thread ) -hallo1- -- [] initial message
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :39 ] (Quarkus Main Thread ) -hallo1- -- [] final message
16:11:07 INFO  [Test                       :35 ] (worker-1            ) -- -- [hallo3] message in worker

I started to investigate from this post:
How to correlate log events in distributed Vertx system
and I landed to this documentation:
https://reactiverse.io/reactiverse-contextual-logging/#_propagation
Unfortunately it still does not work.
Any suggestions?
